# How to add sid to a XMPPBOSHConnection?

Tags: android, smack

I'm having trouble connection to my bosh server, it says it needs "sid":

> org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHException: Connection Manager session creation response did not include required 'sid' attribute

this is how I'm trying to connect / login:

> ```
>         BOSHConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = BOSHConfiguration.builder();
>         configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
>         configBuilder.setHost(HOST);
>         configBuilder.setPort(PORT);
>         configBuilder.setFile(FILE_PATH);
>         configBuilder.setUseHttps(true);
>         configBuilder.setServiceName(SERVICE);
> ```

```
        AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPBOSHConnection(configBuilder.build());
```

> try {
>                   connection.connect();
>               } catch (SmackException e) {

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and resolved when I added below code :

```
Bytestream stream = new Bytestream();
stream.setSessionID(username);
configBuilder.setResource(stream.toXML().toString());
```

Comment: what did u put as "username" the session string?

Comment: can't  get it to work still same error: "Connection Manager session creation response did not include required 'sid' attribute".
can you point me to some resources so I can figure it out?

Comment: Hi Sorin, in my code I just put any String, you can use username or generate long value and parse it to be string. You can see the api in this link https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/bytestreams/socks5/packet/Bytestream.html